# Ayuda con Arduino comunicación serial

Tags: c++, arduino

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Arduino y necesito que al ingresar un número cualquiera de "n" dígitos, un LED parpadee la cantidad de veces del número ingresado. Debo hacerlo con while. Estuve intentando mi código, pero el LED no se detiene al llegar al número ingresado.

```
int numero;
int i=0;
void setup()
{
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    char numero=Serial.read();
    if(numero>=1){
      while(numero>i){
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(500);
      i++;     
      }   
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Por qué pones etiquetas de java y c++? Procura usar sólo etiquetas relevantes a tu pregunta; están para convocar a quienes más conocen de un tema específico

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Habra algún lío al comparar un char con un entero? Posiblemente esté usando el ASCII code del caracter que corresponde al número que leíste. Eso estará muy lejos del valor entero. Hasta donde he visto en [ejemplos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5030086/236345), tu problema se resolvería haciendo la conversión antes de comenzar las comparaciones. Algo así:

```c
int numero;
int i=0;
void setup()
{
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop()
{
  if(Serial.available()>0){
    char numero = Serial.read();
    // Acá convertiríamos el char a entero
    int numInteger = numero - '0';

    if(numInteger >= 1){

      while(numInteger > i){
        digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
        delay(500);
        digitalWrite(13, LOW);
        delay(500);
        i++;     
      }   

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No lo probe, pero creo que la conversion no funciona. *atoi* pide una cadena pero esta recibiendo un caracter.

Comment: Obtengo el siguiente error

Comment: error:   initializing argument 1 of 'int atoi(const char*)' [-fpermissive]

Comment: Perdón. Ya lo edité. Mi c++ está oxidado, que no lo uso hace mucho rato :)

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, si funciona.

Answer (score 1):

A mi parecer, el error está en:

```
if(numInteger >= 1)
```

Ya que comparas caracter con un entero ('1' != 1). Por lo tanto te recomiendo:

```
int num = numero - 48; //Conversion de char a int. Y se guarda en num
```

Con esa linea se puede convertir de manera facil de caracter a entero, usando el valor correspondiente a '0' en la tabla ASCII. https://elcodigoascii.com.ar/

Nota: Con este método de lectura y conversión solo es posible que funcione con valores del 0 a 9.

Comment: Por qué sólo funciona con valores de 0 a 9? Si deseo que de "n" dígitos?

Comment: La razón es que estas leyendo del serial con char. Es decir, puedes recibir sólo 1 digito. En caso de que quieras cualquier numero n, te recomiendo que leas mejor como una entero. 
Esta pagina https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/read/ 
es la documentación oficial de arduino y tiene un ejemplo de como leer el int.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que la siguiente instrucción es incorrecta.

```
char numero = Serial.read();
```

`Serial.read()` retorna un `int`, no `char`.

Además sólo lees un digito; si quieres leer cualquier valor, debes implementar tu propia rutina de lectura, como esta:

```
int leerEntero();

void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  int numero;
  if (Serial.available()) {
    numero = leerEntero();
    for (int i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
      digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
      delay(500);
      digitalWrite(13, LOW);
      delay(500);
    }
  }
}

int leerEntero() {
  char numero[10];
  int c = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (i < 9 && c != '\r') {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
      c = Serial.read();
      if (isdigit(c)) {
        numero[i++] = c;
      }
    }
  }
  numero[i] = 0;
  return atoi(numero);
}
```

Nota: Probada con Arduino Uno.